# Error calling model from controller in magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, model

I have a controller and I want to call specific function of model from  controller file, When I try to call function, I got an error like this :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Lime\Hello\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance
>   of Lime\Hello\Model\Sync, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory given, called in

here's my controller file code:

```
namespace Lime\Hello\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_sync;
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Lime\Hello\Model\Sync $sync)
    {

        $this->_sync = $sync;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $run = $this->_sync;
        echo $run->test();
        exit; 
    }
}
```

here's my model file code:

```
namespace Lime\Hello\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Object;

class Sync extends Object
{
  public function test(){
    return 'a';
  } 
}
```

Comment: Removed `Var/Generation` and `Var/Cache` folder from your magento2 root directory and 
Run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` command

Comment: Just remove var folder from root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change construct of your model as below

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Lime\Hello\Model\SyncFactory $sync)
    {

        $this->_sync = $sync;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Change below execute method code

```
public function execute()
    {
        $run = $this->_sync->create();
        echo $run->test();
        exit; 
    }
```

I have added create() in above code

Comment: thanks it's working, but why?

Comment: SyncFactory i have called model there you need to use create for model instance as i have done in execute method

Comment: solution is working but could you please explore it more why we need write SyncFactory place of simple Sync.

Comment: refer this link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/factories.html